# running iOS 10.0 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network

Tags: ios, swift, connection, ipv6

Iphone app rejected because of the the reason that
“We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad and iPhone running iOS 10.0 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.”
Anyone can help to solve it?

```
import UIKit
let useClosures = false

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let reachability = Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()

    @IBOutlet weak var WebView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()




        let URL = NSURL(string: "https://gph-shop.com/tracing")

        WebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: URL!))

        if (useClosures) {
            reachability?.whenReachable = { reachability in
                print("Reachable")
            }
            reachability?.whenUnreachable = { reachability in
                print("Unreachable")
            }
        } else {
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.reachabilityChanged(_:)), name: ReachabilityChangedNotification, object: reachability)
        }

        reachability?.startNotifier()

        // Initial reachability check when the app starts
        if let reachability = reachability {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                if reachability.isReachable() {
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "wi-fi connected", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)

                    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

                    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                } else {
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Please connect to internet", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)

                    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

                    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    deinit {

        reachability?.stopNotifier()

        if (!useClosures) {
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: ReachabilityChangedNotification, object: nil)
        }
    }


    func reachabilityChanged(note: NSNotification) {
        let reachability = note.object as! Reachability
        // Initial reachability check while surfing in the app
        if reachability.isReachable() {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Reachable", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)

            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Please connect to internet", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)

            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to debug your app in a NAT64 Network.
(You can create it by using your macOS.)

[image: How to create a NAT64 Network.]

And Apple support article is following:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html